# Is there an established recommended maximum intake of cigarettes?

Tags: alcohol, smoking, nicotine

Recommended maximum intake of alcoholic beverages tell you that it's up to 1 drink per day for women and 2 for men.

Is there an equivalent for cigarette smoking?

Comment: Where do you get those figures from? They’re certainly not correct for the U.K. see  https://www.drinkaware.co.uk/alcohol-facts/alcoholic-drinks-units/latest-uk-alcohol-unit-guidance/

Comment: It is currently the recommended limit in the USA.  But from everything I know it's zero, as there is no known safe amount of cigarette smoking - even a single cigarette increases risks.  Alcohol's recommended limit is based on historical data; new studies (including the one that shows the J curve was erroneous) will likely lead to that changing to zero as well.  As it is, many physicians have changed to recommending avoidance entirely or nearly entirely.  I'd put this as an answer but don't have the ability to get the related references together today - someone is welcome to do so.

Comment: @rhialto, what the OP says is from US: https://www.niaaa.nih.gov/alcohol-health/overview-alcohol-consumption/moderate-binge-drinking

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes

It’s zero.

See: Doll, R., & Hill, A. B. (1950). Smoking and carcinoma of the lung; preliminary report. *British medical journal*, 2(4682), 739–748. doi: [10.1136/bmj.2.4682.739](https://doi.org/10.1136/bmj.2.4682.739) pubmed central: [PMC2038856](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2038856/)

And their follow up papers. And pretty much the entire medical literature on smoking.